# Highcharts scatter plot - make tooltip not follow pointer

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I want to have a line-graph where I hover directly over a point, and the tooltip is triggered, and it doesn't follow the pointer.  I don't want the tooltip to be triggered unless I hover directly over a point.  I can use a scatter plot with linewidth to solve the first problem (only show tooltip when hovering directly over a plot).  I can't figure out how to keep the tooltip from following the mouse, though.  I tried setting followPointer to false in various ways, but it didn't seem to be working (http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#tooltip.followPointer)

Here is a fiddle that demonstrates the problem:

http://jsfiddle.net/6uGJp/1/

```
$(function () {
$('#container').highcharts({

    chart: {
        type: 'scatter'
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Nov', 'Dec']
    },
    tooltip: {
        shared: true,
        useHTML: true,
        headerFormat: '<small>{point.key}</small><table>',
        pointFormat: '<tr><td style="color: {series.color}">{series.name}: </td>' +
            '<td style="text-align: right"><b>{point.y} EUR</b></td></tr>',
        footerFormat: '</table>',
        valueDecimals: 2,
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Short',
        lineWidth: 2,
        data: [95.6, 54.4]
    }]

});
```

});

Answer (score 2):

I had this same problem with my series and I changed the following option and it worked fine:

```
plotOptions: {
  series:{
    stickyTracking: false
  }
}
```

Here is an example from the highcharts api document:
[stickyTracking](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/plotoptions/series-stickytracking-false/)

Answer (score 0):

for this you can go with a fixed tooltip like [here](http://jsfiddle.net/RjMJr/)

for this you need

```
 positioner: function () {
                return { x: 80, y: 50 };
            }
```

this will make the tooltip render at afixed position always.

Hope this is what you need

Comment: i may have to do this, but it isn't exactly what i want.  i just want the tooltip to not follow the pointer, once it pops-up on the hovered point.

Comment: but this is the best way where you can fix the tooltip position

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
plotOptions: {
            scatter:{
                     tooltip:{
                             followPointer: false
                     }
            }
}
```